# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client NodeJS with Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios, http-status-code-401

**Description**
Everytime I include `response.send(snapshot.val());`  this error is occurred and the NodeJS server crashed. I am using Postman to test the API endpoint with Header it is worked okay.
**Output**

```
On terminal 401 Unauthorized 

[2020-11-05T13:23:24.421Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

**NodeJS**

```
const getsRoute = require('./routes/gets');
app.use('/api/v1', getsRoute);

//on other file
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
router.get('/products', auth, (req, res) => {
    initialPage.getBusinesses(res);
});
```

**Code to Produce error**

```
const initialPage = {
    getBusinesses(response) {
        ref.orderByKey()
        .limitToLast(20)
        .on('value', function(snapshot){
            response.json(snapshot.val()); 
            return snapshot.val();
        })
    }
}
```

**Client side using React Native**

```
  searchApi = async() => {
        const response = await axios.get('http://33c75838823c90.ngrok.io/api/v1/products',{
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "x-auth-token":"jgiiHDgfdeizI1NiIJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZmEwMWMzZmM4YjIwYjBjZDQyMmJkNzUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDQ0MTAwMDZ0KwFAgVtsJUQw"
                }
            }
        ).catch((error) => {
            console.log("ERROR FROM AXIOS:", error)
          });
        console.log("RESPONSE DATA: %%%%%%%", response.data)
        this.setState({results: [response.data]});
       
    }
```

I have checked so many documents and questions forum but no one get exactly the solution suit for general problem.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client#:~:text=The%20error%20%22Error%3A%20Can',body%20has%20already%20been%20written.)  might be helpful

Comment: FYI: This is a API issue, No need to include Client Code

Comment: I have came across that, but the answer which everyone mentioned I don't understand, maybe I am fairly new to that concept and it would be more helpful if you pin point me to the exact solution. Thanks @Naren

Comment: Can you more details of your code, route, middleware which handling this route

Comment: just this 

router.get('/products', auth, (req, res) => {
    initialPage.getBusinesses(res);
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
getBusinesses(response) {
    ref.orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(20)
    .on('value', function(snapshot){
        response.json(snapshot.val()); 
        return snapshot.val();
    })
}
```

Since you're using `on(...)`, your callback will be called:

1. As soon as the data is loaded,
2. After that, any time the data changes.

The first one is working as intended, but if the data ever changes this means you're trying to send another response, which is what's causing the error.

To solve this, use `once` instead of `on`:

```
getBusinesses(response) {
    ref.orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(20)
    .once('value', function(snapshot){
        response.json(snapshot.val()); 
        return snapshot.val();
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Frank, you have saved me a lot these days.